# CRM 2013 Custom Workflow to retrieve documents from incoming email

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dynamics-crm, email-attachments, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to be able to retrieve attachments from incoming emails and store them into SharePoint. I understand that I cannot use a Plugin for this as it has a 2 minute time out (even an asynchronous one) and it has to be a Custom Workflow Activity.

However, I am not entirely sure regarding how to go about writing this Custom Workflow Activity.

I looked at the sample CWA example that MSDN provides and found the [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg334455.aspx)

I quite do not understand what do the InArgument implies here and what should be the value for my Custom Workflow Assembly.

Comment: I believe this can be done by Exchange/SharePoint themselves, without involving CRM (but alas, I have no first hand experience on this).

Comment: @Alex: Thanks, but we are not using the SharePoint - CRM Connector but the SharePoint team have written a Web Service which is used by CRM and I am writing the code from the CRM perspective. Can you please let me know on which message should I be associating the Workflow (if any?)

Comment: custom workflow activities have also the 2 minute time out

Comment: @GuidoPreite: I believe an on-premise custom workflow activity is not restricted by the 2 minute timeout. I will post a link shortly to the article / SDK where I read it.

Comment: if you register them outside the sandbox you have not the 2 minute timeout. However if your task take longer time a CWA is not suggested, better to use the external webservice to do the job (so the webservice will pull the data from the CRM instead of the CWA to push the data to sharepoint)

Comment: @GuidoPreite: I am sorry, I quite do not understand your statement "if you register them outside the sandbox you have not the 2 minute timeout." Does it mean that if I register them (what - plugins or custom workflow assembly) outside the sandbox, I am restricted to only 2 minutes or there are no restrictions? Also, can you please elaborate on what is meant by using the external web service? How will share point know that an email has come into the system and is associated with a Incident (yes, I need to store only attachments if email is already linked with an Incident)

Comment: inside the sandbox you have the 2 minutes timeout. your CWA will only advise the webservice that it needs to fetch the attachment (passing the email record id), your workflow will end but the webservice will fetch the data.

Comment: @GuidoPreite: Thanks for the clarification. However, the SharePoint WCF functionality as-is has the ability to only AddDocuments (push) instead of ReceiveDocument(pull). So, can I have my custom workflow on a OOB Workflow which is triggered for Incoming email and have the Regarding Object set to Incident which then retrieves the Attachments and calls the AddDocument methods of the SharePoint WCF?

Comment: your CWA will invoke a third webservice that will queue the request and trigger the sharepoint webservice (so you will not have timeout by CRM side)

Comment: @GuidoPreite: Thanks. However, I am afraid that I am officially lost and not because your comment was not clear. But, because, I am a little inexperienced myself. I really do not understand why / how a CWA is not suggested but instead have a Web Service that is advised to pull the attachment. And, I do not understand what you mean by the third web service. Would it be OK if I flag this question for deletion as I do not think this question adds any value to the site. I do apologize if your time had been wasted. Sorry!

Comment: leave the question open, other users can reply in the future or find the comments useful